# Auto Complete jquery json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete, but isn't working, I have an array of JSON objects, and the idea is when someone search for the postcode or town it starts show his JSON object value.

Here is the code:

Json:

```
[ {
"label": "AB10",
"value": "Aberdeen "
},
{
"label": "AB11",
"value": "Aberdeen "
},
...]
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
            var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
            $("#uk_postcode").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                autoFocus:true
            });
        });
```

Comment: _"but isn't working"_  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask _" the idea is when someone search for the postcode or town "_ Are `"label"` properties of objects in array postal codes ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, the ideia is when someone searches for the label it shows the value that is associented, but the idea is if the user searches by the value name it shoes the values tags

Comment: What is currently being returned ? Can create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?